# How to place 2 ion-card in same row just for web view?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to put 2 ion card's in same row. I am building an hybrid app and I need that view only for web so I need to achieve this using CSS. Any one can help with this? I would really appreciate if you guys can share your ideas?

```
<ion-card class="level">
  <ion-card-content>
      <ion-card-title>
          LEVEL
        </ion-card-title>
    <ion-row class="progressWrapper">
      <img src="assets/logo/a.png" style="height: 90px;width: 90px;" />
      <span class="levelText">4</span>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col text-center>
          <ion-text color="dark">abc!</ion-text>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card class="faq">
  <img src="assets/logo/b.svg" class="helpIcon"/>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-card-title>
      XP
    </ion-card-title>
    <ion-row class="progressWrapper">
      <img src="assets/logo/c.svg" style="height: 90px;width: 90px;" />
        <span class="progressText">{{xp}}</span>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
          <ion-col text-center>
            <ion-text color="dark">abc !!!!!.</ion-text>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col text-center>
              <ion-text color="dark">xxxxxxxx.....</ion-text>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I am trying to put 2 ion card's in same row. I am building an hybrid**
>   **app and I need that view only for web**

*If I understand correctly you want the layout of the cards to change from vertically stacked in mobile view to horizontally aligned in desktop view, you can **use a combination of width and breakpoint attributes to create a grid that starts out stacked on extra small screens before becoming horizontal on small screens**, if that's what you need, check the quick sample I made below in ionic3*

> ### **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-responsive-grid-demo?embed=1&file=src/app/home/home.page.html)

**You can modify your HTML to something like below:~**

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row justify-content-end>
    <ion-col padding size-xs="12" size-sm="6" size-md="6" size-lg="6" align-self-stretch>
      <ion-card class="level">
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
            LEVEL
          </ion-card-title>
          <ion-row class="progressWrapper">
            <img src="assets/logo/a.png" style="height: 90px;width: 90px;" />
            <span class="levelText">4</span>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col text-center>
              <ion-text color="dark">abc!</ion-text>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col padding size-xs="12" size-sm="6" size-md="6" size-lg="6" align-self-stretch>
      <ion-card class="faq">
        <img src="assets/logo/b.svg" class="helpIcon" />
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title>
            XP
          </ion-card-title>
          <ion-row class="progressWrapper">
            <img src="assets/logo/c.svg" style="height: 90px;width: 90px;" />
            <span class="progressText">{{xp}}</span>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col text-center>
              <ion-text color="dark">abc !!!!!.</ion-text>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col text-center>
              <ion-text color="dark">xxxxxxxx.....</ion-text>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

**Hope this is helpful!**

Comment: I will not be able to edit HTML file as the current view(cards aligned vertically) is perfect for mobile , I just need same cards to be placed side by side in web view. I need both web and mobile views to work.

Comment: Didn't get you! Have you tested with the code I've provided here? in fact, I've just refactored it to use the grid system as per your need! Just copy paste from here to your app and check ones

Comment: Test ones with this code and let me know if that's what you are expecting, check both mobile and web view with this code and verify !

Comment: Yes what I am trying to tell is two cards should be in vertical line in Mobile view but horizontal in web view. With this code it will be horizontal in both mobile and web . I tried running it.

Comment: @Battu Updated the code and stackblitz demo as well check now, it works as your requirement ! You can resize the stackblitz window and check !

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a container with `display: flex`? Like this:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <ion-card class="level">
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                LEVEL
            </ion-card-title>
            <ion-row class="progressWrapper">
                <img src="assets/logo/level-box.png" style="height: 90px;width: 90px;" />
                <span class="levelText">4</span>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col text-center>
                    <ion-text color="dark">abc!</ion-text>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card class="faq">
        <img src="assets/logo/faq.svg" class="helpIcon" />
        <ion-card-content>
            <ion-card-title>
                XP
            </ion-card-title>
            <ion-row class="progressWrapper">
                <img src="assets/logo/xp-circle.svg" style="height: 90px;width: 90px;" />
                <span class="progressText">{{xp}}</span>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col text-center>
                    <ion-text color="dark">abc !!!!!.</ion-text>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col text-center>
                    <ion-text color="dark">xxxxxxxx.....</ion-text>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</div>
```

Comment: I will not be able to edit HTML file as the current view(cards aligned vertically) is perfect for mobile , I just need same cards to be placed side by side in web view.

Comment: You can use media query for that